# Start coding from the debugging point Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a code like this

```
String s="Test-Code-Data";
String[] splitedData = s.split("-");
```

I have a break point at second line. When my code reaches that point, can i start coding below that and immediately see the output. For example. I want to see the output from below code, and i type it when the execution reaches the second line only.

```
System.out.println(splitedData[1])
```

Is this possible in eclipse?

Comment: Coding, no. But you can examine values in your Variables and Expression windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, NO you cannot effectively alter code while the code is in execution without making Eclipse warn you that the code is 'out of sync'.

However, you can look at the actual values of your various variables in the various stages of execution of your code. And, once the execution is complete, then you can edit the code and Run the program in Debug again and keep going that way.

You can use the `Inspect Variable` feature to look at the value of a variable while in execution and paused at a breakpoint by selecting the variable you'd like to inspect and using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+I` to get the value of the variable.